# C# WinForm: Editing object from list being displayed in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

My ListBox contains part of an Object (Title and Name, object contains 4 strings).
I want to be able to edit the object in a second form via an 'edit' button when the item in the ListBox is highlighted.

This listBox is populated by a datasource on form 2, and the edit form will be form 3.

This is my code for the 'edit' button:

```
    private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object item = listBox1.SelectedItem;
        Form3 MyForm = new Form3();
        MyForm.Owner = this;
        MyForm.Show();
    }
```

How can I then populate the fields in form3 and edit them? :)

Comment: What is the datatype of the item retrieved? You better work with the correct type instead of a generic `object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the item (after appropriate casting) to the Form3 constructor  or use a custom public property on Form3 where you set the item retrieved

For these examples I will assume that every item stored in your listbox is an instance of a class named MyClass (change it with your correct class name)

**Passing the item to Form3 constructor**

```
private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass item = listBox1.SelectedItem as MyClass;
    if(item != null)
    {
         Form3 MyForm = new Form3(item);
         MyForm.Owner = this;
         MyForm.Show();
    }
}
```

and inside the Form3 constructor

```
public class Form3 : Form
{
     MyClass currentItemToEdit = null;
     public Form3(MyClass itemToEdit)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         currentItemToEdit = itemToEdit;
         txtBoxTitle.Text = currentItemToEdit.Title;
         ......
     }
}
```

Using a custom property

Inside the Form3 you define a public property

```
public class Form3 : Form
{
     public MyClass ItemToEdit {get; set;}
     public Form3()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
     protected void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if(this.ItemToEdit != null)
         {
             txtBoxTitle.Text = ItemToEdit.Title;
              ......
         }
     }
}
```

while in the first form you write

```
private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass item = listBox1.SelectedItem as MyClass;
    if(item != null)
    {
         Form3 MyForm = new Form3();
         MyForm.Owner = this;
         MyForm.ItemToEdit = item;
         MyForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first method, this worked great! :) What should I then add to "private void saveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)" to save these changes?:) Would I have to remove the previous object and re-add it as a new one?

Comment: Thanks, I've marked your answer as accepted :) My listbox is loaded via a BindingList, so shouldn't any changes auto-update?